# Server is Able to Decrypt Forms Authentication Key Generated on my Local System

Tags: asp.net, security, forms-authentication

I am in .NET 4.0 paradigm and I noticed a scenario. My API was using `FormsAuthentication.Encrypt` method to create a token for the user. the problem is that if I run the API on localhost, call the api to get the key, I can use the same key on subsequent request to the server. Why is this happening? Is this desired behavior? Isn't it a security risk?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "can use the same key on subsequent request to the server?"  Which key are you referring to?

Comment: In API user passes his u/p and API returns it a key. which will identify him. I create a form ticket, encrypt it and use it as key that user has to forward with each subsequent request. I believe if forms authentication is safe with this method, it should also work securely with the API.

Comment: FormsAuthentication.Encrypt returns a string that you can then pass to FormsAuthentication.Decrypt, which will give you back the original FormsAuthenticationToken that was used to generate the encrypted string.  You can call the Decrypt method multiple times on the same encrypted string, and it should keep returning the same original FormsAuthenticationTicket every time.

Comment: My question is that I am encrypting the ticket on my local system and passing to API on my webserver to my surprise, it was able to decrypt that ticket just fine. why would it happen. It is supposed to work on per machine basis because the machine keys of each system are supposedly different? no?

Comment: Did you set the <machineKey> element to a custom hex key?

Comment: no. neither at server nor at local machine. Should I?

Comment: You don't need to set it explicitly unless you're deploying an application to more than one server.  Is there anything special about your <forms> element in Web.config?

Comment: we have no `forms` element. the authentication element looks like `<authentication mode="None"/>`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15699/discussion-between-levi-and-muhammad-adeel-zahid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that we were overriding the `machineKey` value in our applications web.config. So both applications (running on local machine and server) were using same keys to encrypt and decrypt. Hence, it was possible for server to decrypt key encrypted by local machine and vice versa.